# Linear Algebra, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to (advanced) linear algebra. I was given the problem:  Find values for "c" and "d" for the field $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ where we have cd = 23. 
I do not fully understand how one can find values for "c" and "d". I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}) =\{ a + b\sqrt{7}\}$ but where do "c" and "d" come from? How do I interpret this problem? how do I proceed? 
Thanking all in advance.

Comment: $c,d$ are variables that represent unknown elements of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$. Your job is to solve the equation $cd=23$ for the unknowns $c,d$. The answer of @TommasoScognamiglio shows how to do this by introducing new $\mathbb{Q}$-values $a,b,e,f$ for the coordinates of $c,d$.

Comment: Thank you so much. Both you and Tommaso Scognamiglio have been most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should write $c=a+b\sqrt{7}$ and $d=e+f\sqrt{7}$ so then multiply them and obtain $ae-7fb=23$ and $af+be=0$ and then solve for this equations where $a,b,e,f$ are rationals numbers.

Comment: Thank you. See my comment above. Appreciate time taken to reply and show me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ contains $\mathbb{N}$ so that we let $c=1,\ d=23$.

[Add] $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ is a field so that we choose any $c=a+b\sqrt{7}\neq 0$

Then $$ d=\frac{23}{c}=\frac{23}{a+b\sqrt{7}} = \frac{23(a-b\sqrt{7})}{a^2-7b^2} $$

Comment: This is fairly trivial (but correct) in giving one solution.  There was already an Answer that the OP (judging by their Comment) found satisfactory, but if you want to go beyond that and give more details about *all possible* solutions, it could well make a contribution to the site.

Comment: I see. you are right. I will add more.